# What error code ranges are available for new services in Cloud Foundry?

Tags: service, numbers, cloud-foundry

The various services in .../cloudfoundry/vcap/services/*/lib/*_service/*_error.rb define various errors and use unique numbers. Is there a central allocation authority for these numbers or do we just pick random numbers and wait for conflicts?

Answer (score 1):

There is no central authority for error codes; at this point pick random numbers and be on the lookout for potential conflicts.

FYI, the best place to ask questions about the Cloud Foundry open-source project is the vcap-dev Google Group: http://groups.google.com/a/cloudfoundry.org/group/vcap-dev/